# we're sorry, but something went wrong on heroku when a user tries signing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I can't correctly pinpoint what exactly is causing the issue
This is a new website I just pushed to heroku, ran `heroku rake db:migrate`, and `heroku restart`

It works just fine locally but this happens in production
Here's the relevant portion of heroku logs

```
2013-05-03T23:16:27.189569+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-05-03T23:16:27.189569+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signup" for xx.xx.xx.
xxx at 2013-05-03 23:16:27 +0000
2013-05-03T23:16:27.253381+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_error_messages.h
tml.erb (0.4ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:27.253381+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (
0.0ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:27.253381+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb
 (2.9ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:27.253381+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#new a
s HTML
2013-05-03T23:16:27.253381+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/new.html.erb withi
n layouts/application (43.8ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:27.253381+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 48
.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:27.922135+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favico
n.ico host= sleepy-river-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="xx.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect
=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-05-03T23:16:27.268937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/signup
 host= sleepy-river-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="xx.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms
service=81ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-05-03T23:16:47.934099+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-05-03T23:16:47.934099+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-05-03T23:16:47.934099+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for xx.xx.xx.
xxx at 2013-05-03 23:16:47 +0000
2013-05-03T23:16:48.248989+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://sleepy-river-xxxx.herokuapp.com/home
2013-05-03T23:16:48.248989+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"???", "auth
enticity_token"=>"m+NCbnqHJk81yWgyY+Y709mQZ0N04MpW8MLGLXjbleA=", "user"=>{"name"
=>"testuser", "email"=>"testuser@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "passwo
rd_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
2013-05-03T23:16:48.248989+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 311ms (Activ
eRecord: 70.6ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:48.248989+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#creat
e as HTML
2013-05-03T23:16:48.435265+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-05-03T23:16:48.435265+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-05-03T23:16:48.435265+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/home" for 75.82.32.16
4 at 2013-05-03 23:16:48 +0000
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a L
EFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"h
ashtags"'::regclass
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrel
id = '"hashtags"'::regclass
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.a
drelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:   <%= link_to "#"+h.hashtag
s, "#" %><br>
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649845+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_user_info.html.e
rb (4.4ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PGErro
r: ERROR:  relation "hashtags" does not exist
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <% @htags.each do |h| %>
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649845+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController
#home as HTML
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]:
     ^
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, for
mat_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.
erb:22:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___3097102804728997358_70437520'

2013-05-03T23:16:48.649845+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND
 NOT a.attisdropped
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649331+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:     19: <div class="box">
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:   <% end %>
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:   Tagged Posts
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649617+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:   <br>
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649845+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_stats.html.erb (
38.9ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649845+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error
 in 209ms
2013-05-03T23:16:48.649845+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.e
rb within layouts/application (156.1ms)
2013-05-03T23:16:48.654562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/home h
ost=sleepy-river-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="xx.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms se
rvice=219ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-05-03T23:16:48.253053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users
 host= sleepy-river-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="xx.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms
service=395ms status=302 bytes=109
```

Comment: have you run any necessary database migrations?

Comment: I ran `heroku rake db:migrate` which should be sufficient. Should I try running something else?

Comment: The error seems to be on the database side given the error `PGErro
r: ERROR:  relation "hashtags" does not exist`. Are you sure your production database schema matches development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with the template that is loaded after a user signs up. Try it locally, I bet you'll find the answer you need.

Added hint:

Look at the line `Relation HashTags does not exist`. That holds the key to your problem.

I bet if you run

```
heroku run rake db:setup
```

and

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Your problem will be solved

Comment: I just tried it locally and it works so this is happening only on heroku production

Comment: I saw that error `Relation HashTags does not exist` and I already have the "Hashtags" table inside my schema.db and everything works fine locally but not in production

Comment: run `heroku run rake db:setup`